# Preview/Summary Page

Tags: javascript, forms, html

New to HTML javascript programming and have an issue with implementation of my page.
I have created multipage HTML form layout(using div) which runs 4 pages with approximately 140 input values(most are optional values) all together. I need to implement a preview page before actually submit  where in only filled input values along with their labels are displayed within a  section of the page.I am able to collect the filled input values and the label values to an array using javascript. However the issue is, I am not able to figure out how I can pass these values to the actual  in html summary page? I cannot implement .innerHTML as my labels need to be dynamically generated based on input values. Can this even be done just by javascript or HTML or do I need a server side script to implement the preview page? Does learning DHTML or AJAX help to implement a solution to this problem? I appreciate all the help. Let me know if I need to explain better.

Answer (score 0):

The BEST way would be a session variable in a server-side language. If security is not an issue though, you can save the variables into a cookie though javascript.

See [here.](http://www.w3schools.com/JS/js_cookies.asp)